# How to add sftp permission to user/client?

Tags: permissions, sftp

I'm on a new Centos 7 setup. So far I have logged in via `ssh` as root:

- added a new user
- gave user full permission via `visudo`
- added user to the root group (not sure if this is needed)

Logged out and then logged in with the new user. I had already done a few things with the root user, such as install LAMP and add the directory `/var/www/public_html/test/`

I am able to delete the test directory via SSH, but I am not able to use a SFTP client to do so... when I am using a SFTP client (Transmit for MAC) I get `permission denied`.

So my question is... how do I give my user permissions that will let me use the SFTP client to complete basic operations such as add/remove/move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup the SFTP service (it's part of SSH but often times is disabled). Take a look at my answer to this U&L Q&A titled: [How can I create an SFTP user in CentOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110593/how-can-i-create-an-sftp-user-in-centos).

The key bits are making the following changes to your SSHD setup.

> Make these changes to your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.
>
> ```
>   Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp
>
>   ## You want to put only certain users (i.e users who belongs to 
>   ## sftpusers group) in the chroot jail environment. Add the following
>   ## lines at the end of /etc/ssh/sshd_config
>
>   # Match Group sftpusers  
>   #   ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u  
>   #   ForceCommand internal-sftp
> ```

Then restart your SSHD service:

```
$ sudo service sshd restart
```

Comment: I will give it a try once I get home. Thanks.