# Centos, uploaded files from application have different owner and group

Tags: centos, permissions, directory, group, sftp

I have an application that uploads a file via SFTP using sftpuser. Once the file is uploaded the owner and group is user1:user1. The owner of the parent directory is apache:apache. I can not figure out how the file is being associated to user1.

Any thoughts on where I should look or how to resolve this issue? I would like the file to inherit the owner/group and permissions from the parent directory.

Comment: If I do a chown sftpuser:sftpuser ./ the owner is changed to user1??? Here is what I have in my passwd file.
sftpuser:x:502:503::/home/sftpuser:/bin/bash
user1:x:503:504::/home/user1:/bin/bash

Comment: I resolved my issue. The directory was part of a mounted nsfshare. The UID for sftpuser was 502 on one server and 502 for user1 on the other.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an entry for user1 in your /etc/passwd ?
If you want to change the ownership of the directory you can type as root:
`chown apache:apache /var/www -R` 
You can also add user1 to apache group and in this way your web server will fine. 
Maybe it's good idea to read the following topic:

[How can I create an SFTP user in CentOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110593/how-can-i-create-an-sftp-user-in-centos)

Comment: yes, user1 is a valid user. I know I can manually change the permission but I don't want to login every time a file is uploaded to do so. User1 is not the owner of any of the directories in question nor is it used to upload the files. I have no clue how the files are associated with user1